# LocalStorage - Assign value to setItem then getItem to form field

Tags: javascript, forms

I am using a script that creates a value:

script

The last line is:
getID += final_collected_id || '';

/script

Example: getID looks like: 123456789

I'd like to use localStorage.setItem and assign the value of getID

Not sure how this value is assigned as it is not using a var = getID
but might be the fix?

Then, I would like to use the getItem and output in a form field:

Then use the clear()

I have a form with additional fields and some with HTML design
and attempting to add the getID in a direct java-script didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My comments are in the comments.

```
var getID = 0;
getID += 1234 || '';

// first check value is ok
console.log(getID)

// then store it under name "getID"
localStorage.setItem("getID", getID);

// get the value back (next time)
var value = localStorage.getItem("getID") || '';

// make the form have it
document.getElementById("my-input").value = value;

// if you have a clear button 
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener(function() {
  localStorage.removeItem("getID")
})
```

Comment: Works great!!! Big thanks! I will save your account info. I'm not a front-end design programmer. I do more back-end data management. So it's terrific to connect.

Comment: I made an error. I had this: <input id="my-input" type="hidden" name = "goID" value="" /> from a different test with the value hard coded. I am getting the value in the localStorage, but its not adding to the field. Do I run the script within the form? Or can it be outside of it?

Comment: The script should be at the end of page (or on event "load" of the body), *after* the form and its inputs have been rendered.

Comment: That worked! I was looking at the page source code, and it did not show. But when I posted the form, it did send the value.  Also, I just remove the getID without needing it in the button. I have saved your web site link. I am working on a potentially huge worldwide project. If it gets initiated with some traction I will let you know. Including of course if I get some other ideas.  Again, thank you much!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value by doing:

```
localStorage.setItem('ID', '1234');
```

and you can get the value by doing:

```
localStorage.getItem('ID');
```

then you can define your variable as:

```
const getID = localStorage.getItem('ID') || "1234"
```

I wasn't exactly sure what it was that you were asking because you seemed to demonstrate knowledge of using localStorage in your post.

Comment: I appreciate your post. I used the code provided by kic below, as I'm a newbie to the front-end development.